# Representing quantum channels, and especially measurements, via C*-algebras

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra, research-level

I have not been able to find in my searches a concise explanation of how to think of measurement channels in particular in the $C^*$-algebraic formulation of quantum mechanics. It is also difficult to reconcile the physicist's version of things with the mathematician's. But I would appreciate confirmation (or the opposite) of how I think things go, which is as follows:

1. The $C^*$ algebras correspond to the (possibly bounded) operators on some Hilbert space(s), e.g., $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_1) \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_2)$ or $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H}_1) \to \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H}_2)$. I am happy to restrict to the case where all operators are bounded, if helpful.
2. Valid quantum channels are completely positive trace-preserving (CPTP) maps between the $C^*$-algebras above.
3. These maps can be thought of as acting on the density matrix, and in some cases, an adjoint map acts on observables. The latter is probably true in the case of bounded observables $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$?
4. The expectation value $\left\langle A \right\rangle^{\,}_{\rho}$ of an observable $A \in \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H})$ evaluated in a system with density matrix $\rho$ is given by $\rho(A) = \mathrm{tr} [ \, A \, \rho \,]$, which is the $C^*$-algebra *state* (a positive linear functional). This is a map between the $C^*$-algebras $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H})$ and $\mathbb{C}$, and thus a valid quantum channel.
5. Suppose that the observable $A$ has the spectral decomposition $A = \sum_{n=1}^M a_n P_n$, where $\mathrm{spec}(A) = \{a_1,\ldots,a_M\}$ are the $M$ unique eigenvalues of $A$, and the projection (operators) $P_n$ project onto the $n$th eigenspace of $A$, so that $A \, P_n = a_n P_n$. Then the probability of obtaining outcome $a_n$ is given by $\mathrm{Prob}(a_n) = \left\langle P_n \right\rangle^{\,}_{\rho} = \rho(P_n)$, i.e., the expectation value of the projection $P_n$ if the system has density matrix $\rho$.
6. Most importantly, is the map corresponding to the post-measurement density matrix. I guess I could in principle define the outcome-averaged post-measurement density matrix, but it is likely more useful to define $\rho_n$ as the density matrix following the measurement of $A$ should outcome $a_n$ be observed. In which case, the corresponding map $\Psi_n \, : \, \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H}) \to \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H})$ is given by $\Psi_n (\rho) = P_n \, \rho \, P_n$, where normalization of $\rho$ is not part of the map? But the normalized version is $\rho_n = \Psi_n (\rho) \, / \, \mathrm{Prob}(a_n)$, of course.
7. Finally, is the average post-measurement density matrix given by $\Psi_{\rm av} (\rho)$ $= \sum_{n=1}^M \, \mathrm{Prob}(a_n) \,\rho_n$ $= \sum_{n=1}^M \, \Psi_n (\rho)$ $= \sum_{n=1}^M \, P_n \, \rho \, P_n$? And I think this is the same as the Kraus description of the measurement channel?

My question is which of the points above are correct, and if any are not, how they ought to be fixed. In particular, is what I call $\Psi_n$ (6) the correct $C^*$-algebraic formulation of the map (channel) corresponding to the measurement of $A$ in a system with density matrix $\rho$, given that I observe outcome $n$ corresponding to eigenvalue $a_n$? And is what I call $\Psi_{\rm av}$ (7) the correct outcome-averaged channel, and equivalent to the Kraus version?

My apologies if these points have been answered elsewhere, in which case links would be appreciated. References are also welcome, though direct answers are obviously preferable.